# Set and Limit file type association within the scope of a cmd shell

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

On Windows, is there a way to create a cmd shell and set certain file type associations within it's scope and not affect system-wide file association. I'd like to launch a .bat file to open a shell with it's own defined file type association.... Something like this pseudo .bat file:

```
[my_shell.bat]
@echo off
~ASSOCIATE .jpg --> Google Image Viewer.exe
~ASSOCIATE .tga --> Adobe Photoshop
~ASSOCIATE .txt --> Komodo Edit
start cmd
```

And so, for example, any .txt file i'd open from the resulting shell would open in Komodo Edit, while double clicking a .txt file on my desktop would open it with whatever system-wide file association is defined, like notepad.

Comment: Since file association is stored in the registry, I do not see any way  of isolating such changes.  The effect could be emulated by creating your own command parser to catch the desired file types, but that is kind of a pain.

Comment: You can write a batch file to change the system wide associations and change it back afterward, but there is no method to change it in a local-scope.

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with `assoc` and `ftype`

```
assoc .jpg=picture
ftype picture="C:\Program Files (x86)\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" "%1"
```

(note the output of `assoc .jpg` and `ftype WhateverYouUseAsName` before so that you are able to revert it, if needed)

Comment: Just be aware that this will be a permanent change unless you change it back to whatever it was before, in another batch file.  It doesn't operate as the question describes, but the way the question asks is not possible AFAIK.

Comment: As @foxidrive said, the question was about limiting file type association to the scope of a shell (which may be impossible). What you suggest has a system-wide effect.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve the problem entirely and requires some system wide modifications but at least you can get local scope associations. You can do this by associating the file type to an environment variable and then modify the environment variable in the current cmd scope.

We had the same issue for python files and solved it like this. So first set the file assocation to a variable path.

```
ftype Python.File=%PYTHON%\python.exe "%1" %*
```

and then in the local cmd scope you set the environment variable to the appropriate value.

```
set PYTHON=C:\Python27\2.7.9
```