# To associate file extension with specific program

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-association

I'm trying to associate specific file extensions with specific programs. For example, when I press Enter on `.txt` file, it should be opened in Sublime Text. Or may be in Vim. Or may be in Chrome.

I need to achieve it with command line. At first glance, it could be achieved in the following way:

```
FTYPE txtfile=C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe "%1"
ASSOC .txt=txtfile
```

But actually it does nothing for me: `.txt` files opens in Sublime Text, not in browser.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Pretty sure you need to put quotes are paths with spaces in them. Are you executing this from a batch file or the command prompt? If from a batch file then you need to double the percent symbols to escape them.

Comment: [Refer back to the syntax used in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21951281/12343998)

Comment: You'll note it should be `ASSOC .txt=txtfile` **followed by** `FTYPE txtfile="C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "%1"`

Comment: @T3RR0R Are you sure it works? I pasted the first command, pressed Enter, pasted second command, press Enter. No effect.

Comment: I have tried it with and without administrative privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Try this:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

title <nul && title ...\%~nx0 && cd /d "%~dp0" && mode 50,6 && echo/
for %%i in (ProgramFiles,ProgramFiles(x86^),ProgramW6432)do if /i defined %%~i (
    for /f tokens^=^* %%z in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "!%%~i!" "chrome.exe" 2^>nul
    ')do set "_path_chrome=%%~z" && goto :_reg_add_: 
     )

:_reg_add_:
>nul (
"%__APPDIR__%reg.exe" add "HKCU\Software\Classes\.txt" /ve /d "txtfile" /f
"%__APPDIR__%reg.exe" add "HKCU\Software\Classes\txtfile" /ve /d "Text Document" /f
"%__APPDIR__%reg.exe" add "HKCU\Software\Classes\txtfile\shell\open\command" /ve /d "\"!_path_chrome:\=\\!\" \"file:///%%L\"" /f
) 2>nul && endlocal || (endlocal && echo/Something is very wrong here^!!) & %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1
```

Use **`for`** loop and get the full path to **`Chrome.exe`**, save it to variable and replace **`\`** to **`\\`** for add path value in register...

Add entries in Windows register with this layout:

**1)** Use **`%%L`** instead **`%L`**

**2)** Use **`\"file:///%%L\"`** instead **`\"%L\"`**

**3)** Use **`"\"!_path_chrome:\=\\!\"`** instead **`\"!_path_chrome\"`**

> Use: **`\"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"`**
>
> Not: **`\"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\"`**

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the following to function as intended, *despite my reluctance to advise it*.

*[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)*

```batch-file
@"%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\.txt" /VE /D "txtfile" /F > NUL
@"%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\txtfile" /VE /D "Text Document" /F > NUL
@"%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\txtfile\shell\open\command" /VE /D "\"%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\" \"%%L\"" /F > NUL
```

*[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)*

```batch-file
"%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\.txt" /VE /D "txtfile" /F > NUL
"%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\txtfile" /VE /D "Text Document" /F > NUL
"%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\txtfile\shell\open\command" /VE /D "\"%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\" \"%L\"" /F > NUL
```